# Como transferir arquivo usando socket em python?

Tags: python, socket

Estou fazendo um programa que consiste em passar um arquivo usando protocolo UDP. O usuário que rodar o arquivo `client.py` deverá ter arquivos na pasta raiz do programa para poder transferir para a pasta em que o arquivo `server.py` está. Os programas não chegam a disparar erros, apenas não acontece a transferência.

**Código do server.py**

```
import socket
from os import write
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Endereco IP do Servidor
PORT = 5000            # Porta que o Servidor esta
udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
orig = (HOST, PORT)
udp.bind(orig)
#Até aqui é a conexão sendo realizada

#Ouvindo os nomes dos arquivos do client que o server poderá escolher.
while True:
    msg, cliente = udp.recvfrom(1024)
    msg = msg.decode()
    if(msg == 'stop'):
        break
    print(msg)
#input da opção escolhida pelo server   
opt = str(input())
optB = bytes(opt, encoding='utf-8')
udp.sendto(optB, cliente)    

#tentativa frustrada de receber o arquivo do client
while True:
    dados = udp.recv(1024)
    if not dados:
        break
    write(dados)

udp.close()
```

**Código do cliente.py**

```
import socket, os

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Endereco IP do Servidor
PORT = 5000            # Porta que o Servidor esta
udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
dest = (HOST, PORT)
print('Conectado!')
#Até aqui é a conexão sendo realizada
k = 0 
dirs = os.listdir(".")

#Pegando nome dos arquivos que está na pasta do client e mandando pra o server
for file in dirs:
    i = k
    i = str(i)
    
    msg = '[' + i + '] - ' + file 
    msgB = bytes(msg, encoding='utf-8')    
    udp.sendto(msgB, dest)
    k+=1

#Mandando mensagens pra o server
msgB = bytes ('Escolha uma das opções acima digitando um número:', encoding='utf-8')
udp.sendto(msgB, dest)
msgB = bytes ('stop', encoding='utf-8')
udp.sendto(msgB, dest)

#opção que o server escolheu
opt, server = udp.recvfrom(1024) 
opt = int(opt.decode()) 

#tentativa frustrada de enviar o arquivo
arq = open(dirs[opt], 'rb')
for i in arq.readlines():
    udp.send(i,dest)

udp.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR Tente adicionar uma forma de handshake entre o cliente e servidor ou adicionar um delay entre os pacotes enviados**

O problema se dá no modo em que os pacotes UDPs são tratados. No seu exemplo temos os seguintes requerimentos:

- Perda de pacote = 0%
- Saber quando terminar de enviar ou ler um arquivo de tamanho arbitrário
- Saber lidar com buffers de rede cheios

Infelizmente, o protocolo UDP não possui nenhum dos seguintes, mas mesmo assim é possível tentar fazer uma transferência de arquivos usando o mesmo (dito que a perda de pacote seja aceitavel e voce saiba lidar com pacotes perdidos.)

### Perda de pacote

No seu exemplo, creio que voce tu estás a utilizar o localhost ou uma rede local (o que melhora a situação dos pacotes perdidos.)

### Tamanhos arbitrários

O problema da transferência se dá por causa da ausência de um [handshake](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshake), em outros termos, a negociação sobre a troca de informações entres dois participantes. Uma simples solução para isso seria: enviar o número de pacotes consecutivos a ser enviado, adicionar um time-out no tempo de espera pelos pacotes entre outros.

**ex:**

```
"Se o cliente não mandar nenhum pacote em 5 segundos, terminamos"

"Se tivermos um pacote faltando, mandamos outro pedido ao cliente"

"Depois do cliente mandar X pacotes, terminamos"
```

O método que você usa para fazer o handshake não importa mas sim saber lidar com os melhores e piores casos (perda de pacote, perda de conexão, ordem de pacote errada, etc.)

### Congestionamentos no buffer da rede (Bufferbloat)

O [Bufferbloat](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat) ocorre quando os o buffer da rede se enchem por causa da baixa taxa de transferência do servidor (o servidor não consegue ler os pacotes tão rápido,) com isso, a rede não tem mais espaço para "guardar os pacotes" e os pacotes UDPs que não conseguem entrar no buffer são "perdidos."

Soluções para esse problema seriam: pedir para que os pacotes não recebidos sejam re-enviados, reduzir a velocidade de transferência do cliente, etc.

### Conclusão

Manter a integridade na comunicação usando UDP nao é facil mas pode ser feito. Um exemplo seria [TFPT (Trivial File Transfer Protocol)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol)

## Minha Solução

Advertência: Como tinha dito antes erros como "tamanho do arquivo enviado > tamanho do recvfrom" podem causar erros e reações inesperadas no programa

client.py

```
import socket
import os
import time

# 3 Inicializando client
print("Configurando cliente UDP")
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
sock.connect(ADDRESS)
sock.settimeout(10.0)

# 4 Enviando arquivos ao servidor
file_paths = os.listdir()
print("Enviando nomes dos arquivos...")
for file in file_paths:
    sock.sendall(file.encode())

sock.sendall("stop".encode())


# 7 Esperando resposta do servidor sobre qual arquivo enviar
print("Esperando resposta do servidor...")
msg = sock.recv(4)
index = int.from_bytes(msg, "little")

# 8 Abrindo arquivo para ser enviado

file = open(file_paths[index], "rb")
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_paths[index])  # Size in bits
pacote_em_kilobytes = 512
pacote_em_bytes = pacote_em_kilobytes * 8

# 9 Enviando o numero de pacotes ao servidor
numero_de_pacotes = (file_size // pacote_em_bytes) + 1
sock.sendall(numero_de_pacotes.to_bytes(4, "little"))

# 11 Enviando pacotes
delay = 0.004
tempo_estimado = numero_de_pacotes*(delay*1.2)

print(f"Enviando {numero_de_pacotes} pacotes ao servidor")
print(f"Tempo estimado: {round(tempo_estimado)} sec")


for i in range(numero_de_pacotes):
    packet = file.read(pacote_em_bytes)
    sock.sendall(packet)
    enviado = f"{int((i+1)*pacote_em_kilobytes)}/{int(pacote_em_kilobytes*numero_de_pacotes)}Kb"
    print('\r'+enviado, end='')
    time.sleep(delay)


# Limpando buffers e sockets
sock.close()
file.close()
```

server.py

```
import socket
import time

# 1 Server Setup
print("Configurando servidor UDP")
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.settimeout(10.0)


# 2/5 Esperando receber lista de arquivos do cliente
print("Recebendo lista de arquivos\n")
files = []
while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(512)
    if data.decode(errors="ignore") == "stop":
        break
    file_name = data.decode()
    print(f"[{len(files)}] {file_name}")
    files.append(file_name)

# 6 Enviando ao cliente qual arquivo baixar
file_choice = int(input("\nQual arquivos receber?"))
while not (0 <= file_choice < len(files)):
    print("Opcao invalida!")
    file_choice = int(input("Qual arquivos receber? "))

sock.sendto(file_choice.to_bytes(4, "little"), address)


# 10 Recebendo numero de pacotes
# Queremos saber em quantos pacotes o arquivo sera mandado
data = sock.recv(4)
numero_de_pacotes = int.from_bytes(data, "little")

# 12 Recebendo pacotes
sock.settimeout(5.0)
file = open(files[file_choice], "wb")
pacote_em_kilobytes = 512
pacote_em_bytes = pacote_em_kilobytes * 8

print(f"Recebendo {numero_de_pacotes} pacotes...")
start = time.time()
for i in range(numero_de_pacotes):
    data = sock.recv(pacote_em_bytes)
    file.write(data)
    porcentagem = f"Baixando... {round((100*(i+1))/numero_de_pacotes, 2)}%"
    # print(porcentagem)
    print('\r'+porcentagem, end='')

tempo_de_download = round(time.time()-start, 2)
print(f"\nO download foi completo em {tempo_de_download} sec")

# Limpando buffers e sockets
file.close()
sock.close()
```